# CocoaPod: Unable to find Google-Api-Client/Services/Calendar

Tags: objective-c, google-api, cocoapods

I've got a iOS Objective C project with Podfiles which is complaining about:

> Unable to find a specification named `Google-API-Client/Services/Calendar` in `Google-API-Client (0.1.1)`.

I am unsure of how to fix this.

The pod file itself;

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

# Google APIs

# Calendar
pod 'Google-API-Client/Services/Calendar'
```

I've tried searching online, I can see the pod file spec on github, I can even find it on cocoa pods website, but it does not appear to be able to install this particular pod file.

Is there a route to installing this pod file which I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fired it out, I just did a pod for the entire Google API and it seemed to work.

`pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 0.1'`

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I had a similar problem (except using Drive). In my case the issue was the word `Services`.

I ended up using:

`pod 'Google-API-Client/Drive'`

Since I didn't really want all the other services along with it.

Comment: How do you actually import the files from Drive? I'm doing it now and i'm not able to.