# GoogleAPIClient - GTLDrive.h not found

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, cocoapods, google-api-client

I want to do google drive integration in my app, trying the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart).

Basically, while installing pod, there was some issue finding out the pod, giving following message:

> Unable to find a specification for `GoogleAPIClient/Drive (~> 1.0.5)`

I modified the pod file as follows:

> platform :ios, '9.0'
>
> target 'QuickstartApp' do
>
> pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :git => 'https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher.git'
>
> pod 'GoogleAPIClient', :git => 'https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client.git'
>
> pod 'GTMOAuth2', :git => 'https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2.git'
>
> end

Now, pods are being added to the project successfully, but when I search for **GTLDrive.h**, I do not find the header file. Here, is the screenshot.

[image: GTLDrive.h is missing]

Let me know what I am missing / doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the workaround given in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185613/cocoapod-unable-to-find-google-api-client-services-calendar) by adding a pod for the entire Google API: `pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 0.1'`. Also check this [related forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-objectivec-client/cgdMvJFa8Uw) which suggested to run `'pod repo update'`. You may not have the pod in your local copy of the spec repository. Be also noted that the podspec may have a higher minimum version/different set of platform specifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "Google-API-Client" is no more officially supported. I tried with entire "GoogleAPIClient" pod. Also, already gone through the post on the forum, and ensured the minimum version is not higher.